Disable Apyrse loading Typefaces in Background
I need some help with the Apryse Web Viewer in my Angular project. I have a large number of PDF files that users can open in the Web Viewer to edit or fill out. However, I've noticed that the default typefaces are being loaded in the background every time, which is slowing down my app. Since I don't need these typefaces, is there a way to disable their rendering to improve performance? I'd appreciate any advice, feedback, or documentation links that could help.
Thanks!
I've gone through the official Apryse documentation, but I haven't found anything that addresses my issue. I also tried disabling the font selection dropdown, but that only removes it from the UI. I even attempted to disable all fonts and assign a custom font, but it didn't work. Apryse still throws an error in the devTools terminal, complaining that the Typefaces are missing.
Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated!

It's unclear if you are talking about fonts loaded by WebViewer for the UI, or fonts specific to viewing a PDF file itself. Could you please provide screenshots of this " default typefaces are being loaded in the background" issue?

Also, "which is slowing down my app." how did you determine that exactly?

Okay, to answer your question. From what i understand and been using Apryse. Apryse has a couple of Typefaces which they load every time you open the WebView and fill a PDF file. Now loading these Fonts which are 12 or something costs loading time. How I determine “which is slowing down my app” is by looking at the DevTools and reading the speed and loading analytics. I got some instructions form Apryse Discord server, will try that and see if it solves my problem. This is the link to their doc: https://docs.apryse.com/documentation/web/faq/self-serve-substitute-fonts/

Did the documentation help you resolve the issue? I checked with the dev team, and no font fetching should block the UI, it should all be background loading. Whether those fonts are needed for the UI, or for rendering the PDF itself. If you still have the issue, I would suggest submitting a ticket to Apryse support directly to get further help.
